# How can I have a none to one or many parameter list in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, get

I want to capture requests like these three:

```
http://localhost:55835/Home/Print?storeName=MyStore    
http://localhost:55835/Home/Print?storeName=MyStore&p.0=Dogs&p.1=Cats    
http://localhost:55835/Home/Print?storeName=MyStore&p.0=Dogs&p.1=Cats&p.2=Mice
```

I would like something not hard coded but I don't know what type to use for the set of `p.*` parameters?

```
public ActionResult Print(string storeName, string[] p)
{
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you have the option to change the URL format, but you can keep the action method as is, if you do:

```
http://localhost:55835/Home/Print?storeName=MyStore&p=Dogs&p=Cats&p=Mice
```

Comment: Right, I can get it to work like you mentioned. But it's more of a "how did they do that" kind of question. I mean, you can't have a parameter name with a `.` and you can't create an object with numeric properties `1`,`2`,etc so I'm just curious how that is even possible?